# Converting sinusoidal to WGS - MODIS TIFF file too big with R

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, modis, gdalutils

I am interested by MODIS product. I've converted HDF file to TIFF with R and `gdalUtils`. I used a method similar to this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36772341/reading-hdf-files-into-r-and-converting-them-to-geotiff-rasters

But I found that the product is in sinusoidal projection, and I want to convert it to WGS84. I have tested with R, but files is maybe too big (too many cells because it is a high resolution, more details of the product here https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/mod17a3hgfv006/)

I use the following code, where I'm loading first the convert tiff file (and found TIFF fill for the specific year, here 2000). Then I created an empty raster with world extent and define a projection. I finally use mosaic_rasters, to combine all the different TIFF files together.

```
listtiff <- list.files(, pattern = "\\.tif$", full.names = TRUE) 
  
subfileyear <- listtiff[grepl(paste0(2000), listtiff)] #find file with pattern "2000"
  
e <- raster::extent(-180.0000, 180,  -90.0000  , 90.0000)
template <- raster::raster(e)
#proj4string(template) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
proj4string(template) <- CRS("+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs")
writeRaster(template, file="NPP2000.tif", format="GTiff", overwrite = TRUE)
mosaic_rasters(gdalfile=subfileyear,dst_dataset="NPP2000.tif",of="GTiff" , gdalwarp_index = 1)
```

If I'm using gdal info I obtain this, but now I do not know how to convert it to a wgs84??

I tried to use `projectRaster` but it did not work well, I think it's due to the large number of pixels. Do you know other option for conversion from ellipsoide to WGS84?

```
> gdalinfo("NPP2000.tif")
 [1] "Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF"                                                     
 [2] "Files: NPP2000.tif"                                                        
 [3] "Size is 86400, 36000"                                                      
 [4] "Coordinate System is:"                                                     
 [5] "PROJCRS[\"unnamed\","                                                      
 [6] "    BASEGEOGCRS[\"Unknown datum based upon the custom spheroid\","         
 [7] "        DATUM[\"Not_specified_based_on_custom_spheroid\"," 
 [8] "            ELLIPSOID[\"Custom spheroid\",6371007.181,0,"                  
 [9] "                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1,"                                   
[10] "                    ID[\"EPSG\",9001]]]],"                                 
[11] "        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,"                                           
[12] "            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,"                      
[13] "                ID[\"EPSG\",9122]]]],"                                     
[14] "    CONVERSION[\"Sinusoidal\","                                            
[15] "        METHOD[\"Sinusoidal\"],"                                           
[16] "        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",0,"                      
[17] "            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],"                     
[18] "            ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],"                                           
[19] "        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",0,"                                    
[20] "            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],"                                      
[21] "            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],"                                           
[22] "        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",0,"                                   
[23] "            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],"                                      
[24] "            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],"                                          
[25] "    CS[Cartesian,2],"                                                      
[26] "        AXIS[\"easting\",east,"                                            
[27] "            ORDER[1],"                                                     
[28] "            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1,"                                       
[29] "                ID[\"EPSG\",9001]]],"                                      
[30] "        AXIS[\"northing\",north,"                                          
[31] "            ORDER[2],"                                                     
[32] "            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1,"                                       
[33] "                ID[\"EPSG\",9001]]]]"                                      
[34] "Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2"                                        
[35] "Origin = (-20015109.353999998420477,10007554.676999999210238)"             
[36] "Pixel Size = (463.312716527770533,-463.312716527777638)"                   
[37] "Metadata:"                                                                 
[38] "  AREA_OR_POINT=Area"                                                      
[39] "Image Structure Metadata:"                                                 
[40] "  INTERLEAVE=BAND"                                                         
[41] "Corner Coordinates:"                                                       
[42] "Upper Left  (-20015109.354,10007554.677) (124d17'29.21\"W, 90d 0' 0.00\"N)"
[43] "Lower Left  (-20015109.354,-6671703.118) (  0d 0' 0.00\"E, 60d 0' 0.00\"S)"
[44] "Upper Right (20015109.354,10007554.677) (124d15' 5.75\"E, 90d 0' 0.00\"N)" 
[45] "Lower Right (20015109.354,-6671703.118) (  0d 0' 0.00\"W, 60d 0' 0.00\"S)" 
[46] "Center      (      -0.000, 1667925.780) (  0d 0' 0.00\"W, 15d 0' 0.00\"N)" 
[47] "Band 1 Block=86400x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray"                         
[48] "  NoData Value=32767"                                                      
[49] "  Offset: 0,   Scale:0.0001"
```

Comment: What does "it did not work well" mean? Did you get some errors? Please edit your question and show us what went wrong. But yes, that is a very large raster.

Comment: It takes a lot of times, and R crash (I obtain a message R session aborted). 

I tried with only one year, and when it works (after restarting R session after loading the raster for example) I have a similar issue to this person, where I have only data in the "northern" hemisphere : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47800587/convert-global-map-from-sinusoidal-to-wgs84-using-projectraster-and-part-of-the

The problem is that I do not want to aggregate the data to a lower resolution

Answer (score 2):

Just taking a shot here.. I've worked with big raster datasets a lot recently, and while I mostly use R, for converting to a new projection I found that QGIS is much more efficient.
So my advice would be to try to open your raster in QGIS and use "Raster"->"Projections"->"Warp (Reproject)". You can then save your re-projected raster, load it into R and keep going from there..

Answer (score 1):

Using the [answer of @Lena](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/386396/115), I maybe found a R solution with the `gdalUtils`

You can directly reproject it with the following code, where you specify your raster file, the destination file (where `outdire` is the path where I want to put the results), with the projection of the MODIS product and the desire projection (here WGS84). Faster if you have mutlpile rasters to convert, and faster than `raster` package

```
gdalwarp("NPP2000.tif",dstfile=file.path(outdir,"NPP2000.tif"),s_srs = "+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs",
         t_srs='+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0',output_Raster=TRUE, overwrite=TRUE,verbose=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python users, I have written a short [article](https://bpostance.github.io/posts/processing-large-spatial-datasets.md/) and [Gist](https://gist.github.com/bpostance/dda44bcabbfe5879c9bcd759a1b4bfb5) explaining how to perform this translation in GDAL and Rasterio.

```
from osgeo import gdal
  
in_file = f"./modis.hdf" # raw MODIS HDF in sinusoid projection
out_file = f"./modis.tif"
    
# open dataset
dataset = gdal.Open(in_file,gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
subdataset =  gdal.Open(dataset.GetSubDatasets()[0][0], gdal.GA_ReadOnly)

# gdalwarp
kwargs = {'format': 'GTiff', 'dstSRS': 'EPSG:4326'}
ds = gdal.Warp(destNameOrDestDS=out_file,srcDSOrSrcDSTab=subdataset, **kwargs)
del ds
```