# Unable to process HDF files in R due to unavailability of "gdalUtils" package

Tags: coordinate-system, r, geotiff-tiff, hdf, hdf5

I have MODIS HDF files which have sinusoidal projection. I want to do three processes:

1. Convert HDF files to TIFF
2. Change projection from sinusoidal to WGS84
3. Creating subset of region of interest

I am trying to follow answers given at [Converting sinusoidal to WGS - MODIS TIFF file too big with R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/386381/converting-sinusoidal-to-wgs-modis-tiff-file-too-big-with-r) and [Reading HDF files into R and converting them to GeoTIFF rasters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36772341/reading-hdf-files-into-r-and-converting-them-to-geotiff-rasters) but I am unable to do so because it says gdalUtils package is not available in R anymore.

How can I convert MODIS HDF files to TIFF in R? I can create subset of ROI if the above-mentioned first two processes are solved.

Update: Trying code given in answer for processing multiple files:

```
iter <- gdal_utils(
 util = "warp",
 source = sds,
 destination = file.path(path = "D:/Test_MODIS", "MOD11B_h14v041_WGS84.tif"),
 options = c("-t_srs", "EPSG:4326"))

 r <- rast(file.path(path = "D:/Test_MODIS", "MOD11B_h14v041_WGS84.tif"))

for(n in iter){writeRaster(iter[[n]], paste0(n,".tif"))}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a less known [gdal_utils()](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/gdal_utils.html) function in `sf` that you can use. You don't specify any information on the actual data you are working with. So, in the example below I am using a data set from the R package [MODIStsp](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=MODIStsp) which is from the [MOD11B2](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/mod11b2v006/) 8-day Land Surface temperature collection. I'll leave the subsetting of the ROI to you.

**EDIT**

I edited the code to showcase how you could approach using a for loop to iterate over multiple files. You will have to adjust the file paths to your local requirements as well as to make sure that the correct subdataset is selected.

```r
# info about the data: https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/mod11b2v006/

library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.1, GDAL 3.6.2, PROJ 9.1.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.40
library(MODIStsp)

# I create a temporary location - this would be the directory with your HDF files
indir <- tempfile() # adjust this to the path of your directory with HDFs
outdir <- tempfile() # adjust this to the path where you want the GTiff files
dir.create(indir, showWarnings = FALSE)
dir.create(outdir, showWarnings = FALSE)

# This part is just to have some data
# the code below it will assume that in the loc dir there are multiple HDFs

file <- system.file("testdata", "MOD11B2.A2017001.h14v04.006.2017013155631.hdf.zip", package = "MODIStsp")
unzip(file, exdir = indir)

# assuming indir is a directory with your files this will list all HDFs
files <- list.files(indir, pattern = ".hdf$", full.names = TRUE)

# now we iterate over the HDFs
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  file <- files[i] # get the current file path
  bn <- basename(file) # get only the filename
  new_file <- gsub(".hdf$", ".tif", file) # change file extension
  sds <- gdal_subdatasets(file)[[1]]) # potentially adjust the index to your needs
  gdal_utils(
    util = "warp",
    source = sds,
    destination = file.path(outdir, new_file),
    options = c("-t_srs", "EPSG:4326"))
}
```

Comment: Thank for the response. I am using MCD43A3 Version 6.1 (https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/mcd43a3v061/) and my files are in .hdf, not zipped.  I am able to run the code by skipping unzip(...) line and defining path in place of loc everywhere afterwards. But I do not want to define path again and again. Also, I want to run the code to choose and output multiple files. Could you please help me by modifying the code for HDF files, not zipped and for multiple files. I am able to choose multiple files as input but not able to get multiple outputs.

Comment: Without more details about your file structure you will have to adapt the code above by yourself. You can assume the variable `file` to be a single file in your directory, for example. You can then apply a for-loop or `purrr::walk` if you put the warp code into a function.

Comment: I tried using a for-loop but no success. Could you please help me in modifying the code to apply for loop (to process multiple HDF files). What file structure details do you need?

Comment: With the latest edits, were you able to get the for loop working for your data?

Comment: Yes, it is working fine. Thank you for the answer.