# Process multiple MODIS HDF images iteratively in R

Tags: r, modis, sf, terra, modis-reprojection-tool

I have various files of MODIS MCD43A3 Version 6.1 (lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/mcd43a3v061). The files are in HDF format. I am using following code in R to change the sinusoidal projection of MODIS files to WGS84 and, to convert MODIS HDF file to TIFF format. With *list.files*, I am able to input multiple files but in later steps, the code considers and processes only first file and, provides output only for the first file. However, I want it to process and run for all the files kept in my folder.

How can I modify the code accordingly?

```
library(sf)
library(terra)
library(MODIStsp)

setwd("D:/Test")

#loc <- tempfile()
#dir.create(loc)

file <- system.file("MCD43A3.A2010234.h11v04.061.2021169181520.hdf", package = "MODIStsp")
file <- list.files(path = "D:/Test", full.names = TRUE)
file

(sds <- gdal_subdatasets(file1)[[1]])

gdal_utils(
  util = "warp",
  source = sds,
  destination = file.path(path = "D:/Test", "2021169181520.tif"),
  options = c("-t_srs", "EPSG:4326"))

(r <- rast(file.path(path = "D:/Test", "2021169181520.tif")))
```

Comment: Do you need to write a `for` loop over the list of files in `file` and create input and output file names to pass to `gdal_utils`?

Comment: @Spacedman I want to apply a 'for' loop to input all HDF files and retrieve output (with changed projection) as TIFF files.

Comment: Yes. Have you tried? Do you know how `for` loops work in R?

Comment: @Spacedman I have beginner's level of proficiency. I tried to store gdal_utils in an object 'iter' and in the end, I tried for(n in iter){writeRaster(iter[[n]], paste0(n,".tif"))} but it gave me error. I am not clear how to apply for loop here. Kindly help.

Comment: This question is related to another one raises [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/462811/unable-to-process-hdf-files-in-r-due-to-unavailability-of-gdalutils-package/462825#462825) before. I edited my answer to show how this problem could be approached using a for loop.